# WP Как получить посты из custom type_post?

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin

Всем привет! Имеется кастомный тип поста "Фильм" и я хочу вывести все его записи  на страницу. WP предоставляет какой-то файловый шаблон для пользовательских типов постов на которой можно вывести все эти записи? Или для отображения записей мне необходимо создать отдельную страницу на которой через запрос я буду получать записи с указаного типа поста?

Гуглил, нашел только инфу что вп предоставляет следующие файлы для кастомных типов постов:

- single-{type_post}.php
- archive-{type_post}.php

Но это не совсем то

Может быть существуют еще какие-то?

Comment: Установите плагин ultimate shortcodes и там запись есть шоркод 
зайдя в директорию плагина(перейдите в templates и там есть примеры можете свой там создать по их аналогу и после выводить через шоркоды заменяя название в шорткоде на ваш шаблон.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress не предоставляет такого шаблона для кастомных постов по умолчанию, просто потому, что не знает, как вы назовёте свой тип поста.

Вам надо создать файлы

- single-{type_post}.php
- archive-{type_post}.php

в корне темы и наполнить их содержанием. В качестве примера можете взять

- single.php
- archive.php

Так вы получите вывод при стандартном запросе вида `site.org/post_slug`. Если же вам надо вывести кастомные посты на какую-то страницу, то в шаблоне этой страницы должен быть примерно такой код:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'ваш_тип_поста',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // Ваш код по выводу поста
    }
} else {
    echo 'Ничего не найдено';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```